# Add appengine sdk to python path

Tags: python, google-app-engine, path, pythonpath

I am using Appengine and I am following a tutorial on how to use remote_api on an application.
My problem is that I have to add Appengine SDK to Python path, but it doesn't explain me how to do it.
Someone could explain me how can I add the Appengine SDK to python path please? I am a bit newish to this.
Thank you very much!

Comment: `sys.path.append(`directory-name `)`

Answer (score 8):

Put this into `~/.profile`.

```
export CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR="/path/to/google/cloud/sdk/"
export APPENGINE_HOME="${CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR}/platform/appengine-java-sdk"
export GAE_SDK_ROOT="${CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR}/platform/google_appengine"

# The next line enables Java libraries for Google Cloud SDK
export CLASSPATH="${APPENGINE_HOME}/lib":${CLASSPATH}

# The next line enables Python libraries for Google Cloud SDK
export PYTHONPATH=${GAE_SDK_ROOT}:${PYTHONPATH}

# * OPTIONAL STEP *
# If you wish to import all Python modules, you may iterate in the directory
# tree and import each module.
#
# * WARNING *
# Some modules have two or more versions available (Ex. django), so the loop
# will import always its latest version.
for module in ${GAE_SDK_ROOT}/lib/*; do
  if [ -r ${module} ]; then
    PYTHONPATH=${module}:${PYTHONPATH}
  fi
done
unset module
```

Do not put inside `~/.bashrc` because, every time you open a bash session, all those modules will be added again and again into your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` file:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/google/app/engine/sdk/"
```